# Paperclip not replacing the cropped image. at s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, jcrop

I am using paperclip for uploading the images. My storage space is at S3. I am using Jcrop with paperclip for crop the images and have followed the #RailsCast182.

Everything is working smoothly, there were some issues in the RailsCast which i have resolved.

I want to process the crop file and upload it at s3.

Here is my log showing that image is cropped

---

```
Command :: file -b --mime-type '/tmp/249ac5b855195d2e761e123315dd229b20140701-3395-1mz9lji'

Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl[0]' 2>/dev/null

Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl[0]'

Command :: convert '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl[0]' -crop 2586x2586+2534+0 -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl20140701-3395-stdr75'

convert.im6: geometry does not contain image `/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/574.

Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl20140701-3395-stdr75'

Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl[0]' 2>/dev/null

Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl[0]'

Command :: convert '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl[0]' -crop 2586x2586+2534+0 -auto-orient -resize "50x50>" '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl20140701-3395-bhth1i'

convert.im6: geometry does not contain image `/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/574.

Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/4e6c43285b27dbc35603a428c4e4ca9920140701-3395-moimyl20140701-3395-bhth1i'

After that it shows that image is uploaded at s3 but it was the same org image that uploaded.
```

---

My attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_attached_file :file, styles: { medium: "100x100>", thumb: "50x50#" }, :processors => [:cropper]

    attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end
end

#paperclip custom cropper

module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if crop_command
        crop_command + super.join(' ').sub(/ -crop \S+/, '').split(' ')
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        ["-crop", "#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}"]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But paperclip never change the image at S3.

I have gone through many link but didn't touch the sky.

Looking forward a help from great community.

Regards
Adam

Answer (score 0):

You need to change cropper.rb in your lib. Cropper work correct but take only image center. If you change you cropper.rb your images saves fine

```
module Paperclip  
  class Cropper < Thumbnail  
    def transformation_command  
      if crop_command
        original_command = super
        if original_command.include?('-crop')
          original_command.delete_at(super.index('-crop') + 1)
          original_command.delete_at(super.index('-crop'))
        end
        crop_command + original_command
      else  
        super  
      end  
    end  

    def crop_command  
      target = @attachment.instance  
      if target.cropping?
        ["-crop", "#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}"]
      end  
    end  
  end  
end
```

and then you need check your code in model

```
def avatar_geometry(style = :original)
    @geometry ||= {}
    avatar_path = (avatar.options[:storage] == :s3) ? avatar.url(style) : avatar.path(style)
    @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(avatar_path)
  end
```

if s3 save all file in one size you need to change this code to

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
      :thumb => {:geometry => "90x50#", :processors => [:cropper, :thumbnail]},
```

Attention! You need restart your server after change this file